# Which flavour of .net is better for E-Commerce Website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, e-commerce

I am new to ASP.NET. and having big job converting ASP E-commerce website (It has lots of things those are customised like business logic, having own Database structure) to ASP.NET. Here, I am getting confused with some issues... I am writing this here after having lots of thinking of these issues but still they are unsolved. I have estimated 8-10 weeks for these job, and this is 2nd week is going on...

- Is it better to create E-Commerce website from scratch or Modify current available Solutions?
- If Creating new one, than which one is better ? ASP.NET Web Forms using N-tier Structure or MVC (Having no experience in this)
- Is it true that MVC makes website access faster than Web Forms does?
- Or its better to take some time, learn MVC and go ahead?

I think, may be there are questions like these, than please redirect me on that.
Thanks.

Comment: I use MVC and the Entity Framework to build e-Commerce sites and I find it to be a powerful and flexible combination that's getting better and better all the time, especially with the introduction of the Razor view engine. Forget web-forms

Comment: I agree that MVC and EF are perfect for the solution, but if he needs to learn how to use it before he starts he's going to delay the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know web forms, use web forms. Web forms is still a good technology with great third-party controls. There's no reason to use an unfamiliar technology.

Comment: I have started my project with web forms

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the EF mentioned and came across http://efvote.wufoo.com/forms/z7x3p9/
Apparently there is a list close to 1000 experts including MVPs that state that EF is no longer a viable option unless MS invests in its improvement.